# Split on either a space or a hyphen?

Tags: python, string, formatting

In Python, how do I split on either a space or a hyphen?

Input:

```
You think we did this un-thinkingly?
```

Desired output:

```
["You", "think", "we", "did", "this", "un", "thinkingly"]
```

I can get as far as

```
mystr.split(' ')
```

But I don't know how to split on hyphens as well as spaces [and the Python definition of split only seems to specify a string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html). Do I need to use a regex?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If your pattern is simple enough for one (or maybe two) `replace`, use it:

```
mystr.replace('-', ' ').split(' ')
```

Otherwise, use RE as suggested by [@jamylak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16926888/2289509).

Answer (score 20):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "You think we did this un-thinkingly?"
>>> re.split(r'\s|-', text)
['You', 'think', 'we', 'did', 'this', 'un', 'thinkingly?']
```

As @larsmans noted, to split by multiple spaces/hyphens (emulating `.split()` with no arguments) used `[...]` for readability:

```
>>> re.split(r'[\s-]+', text)
['You', 'think', 'we', 'did', 'this', 'un', 'thinkingly?']
```

Without regex (regex is the most straightforward option in this case):

```
>>> [y for x in text.split() for y in x.split('-')]
['You', 'think', 'we', 'did', 'this', 'un', 'thinkingly?']
```

Actually the answer by [@Elazar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16926952/1219006) without regex is quite straightforward as well (I would still vouch for regex though)

Comment: I think regex are better for the general case (any hyphen, say) where `replace` is better for simpler cases.

Comment: And I suggest you'll embed my answer into yours, and I'll remove it. so the reader will get a complete picture.

Comment: @Elazar yes `replace` could get messy after more than one, it works perfectly here though. I do not want to embed your answer, you deserve the votes for it

Comment: and the reader deserves the explanation how to choose... though I guess the comments are doing that already.

Answer (score 1):

A regex is far easier and better, but if you're staunchly opposed to using one:

```
import itertools

itertools.chain.from_iterable((i.split(" ") for i in myStr.split("-")))
```