# Split an input into two. Python 3

Tags: python, split

I've used this method before but can't find it in any of my codes so here I am on Stack Overflow :) What I'm trying to do is split an input into two( the user is asked to enter two digits separated by space). How would you call the first digit a and the second digit b ? The code so far doesn't seem to work.

```
a,b= input(split" "("Please enter two digits separated by space"))
```

Comment: Consider attempting to locate relevant documentation before posting syntactically invalid code in a question. To wit: this is really basic stuff; please make a concerted effort.

Comment: -1 for lack of research effort. There are tonnes of dupes for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: split on either a space or a hyphen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926870/python-split-on-either-a-space-or-a-hyphen)

Comment: Also downvote for showing zero motivation for doing basic research

Answer (score 12):

You're calling the function wrongly.

```
>>> "hello world".split()
['hello', 'world']
```

`split` slits a string by a space by default, but you can change this behavior:

```
>>> "hello, world".split(',')
['hello', ' world']
```

In your case:

```
a,b= input("Please enter two digits separated by space").split()
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function is an *attribute* of the type *str* (string). To call it, you do:

```
input("Please enter two digits separated by space").split()
```

Note that `.split(" ")` isn't needed as that is what it is by default.