# Python: Seperate Values in List in One Input

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is it possible to add different values in one input?

This is the code I have right now:

```
list[]
fruits = input("What are you favorite fruits? Separate each one by comma's.)
list.append(fruits)
print(list)
```

But the result is:

```
['Apple,Banana,Strawberry,Orange']
```

How can I make the result a different value/each single value for each fruit? Like so...

```
['Apple', 'Banana', 'Strawberry', 'Orange']
```

Comment: @Andy - Thanks Andy. I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063114/split-an-input-into-two-python-3

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after Andy posted a link to another similar question.

[Split an input into two. Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063114/split-an-input-into-two-python-3)

```
>>> "hello, world".split(',')
['hello', ' world']
```