# How to split a compound word split by hyphen into two individual words

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have the following list

```
list1= ['Dodd-Frank', 'insurance', 'regulation']
```

I used the following to remove the hyphen

```
new1 =[j.replace('-', ' ') for j in list1]
```

The result I got

```
new1= ['Dodd Frank', 'insurance', 'regulation']
```

The result that Ideally want is

```
new1= ['Dodd', 'Frank', 'insurance', 'regulation']
```

How can I accomplish this in the most pythonic (efficient way)

Comment: Related: [Split on either a space or a hyphen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16926870/7851470)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list1 = ['Dodd-Frank', 'insurance', 'regulation']
new1 = '-'.join(list1).split('-')
print(new1)
```

Prints:

```
['Dodd', 'Frank', 'insurance', 'regulation']
```

Answer (score 2):

## From Ugly to Beautiful

Beautiful is better than ugly.

But it's usually rewarding to move from ugly code to beautiful code. So, we'll first attack this problem using **loops**, and then we'll massage the *loop-y* solution into a **one-liner** in a number of steps.

### A First Attempt

```py
res = []
for item in list1:
    sublist = item.split("-")
    for subitem in sublist:
        res.append(subitem)
```

### A Second Attempt

We can do better by splitting `sublist` in the header of the inner `for` loop, in order to avoid the assignment just before the loop.

```py
res = []
for item in list1:
    for subitem in item.split("-"):
        res.append(subitem)
```

### And for the Final Act...

Now that we have our loop in *iterate-then-append* form, we can conveniently massage it into a one-liner.

```py
res = [subitem for item in list1 for subitem in item.split("-")]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list2 = []
[list2.extend(i.split("-")) for i in list1]
```

list2:

```
['Dodd', 'Frank', 'insurance', 'regulation']
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a single list comprehension, without needing you to
construct any intermediate data structures:

```
my_list = ['Dodd-Frank', 'insurance', 'regulation']

def split_hyphens(lst):
    return [i for word in lst for i in word.split("-")]

print(split_hyphens(my_list))
```

with output

```
['Dodd', 'Frank', 'insurance', 'regulation']
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation using `yield from`

```
list1= ['Dodd-Frank', 'insurance', 'regulation']

def hyphen_split(list1):
    for sublst in list1:
        yield from sublst.split("-")

print(list(hyphen_split(list1)))
```

Output

```
['Dodd', 'Frank', 'insurance', 'regulation']

[Program finished]
```