# How to split compound word in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have and document that consist of many compounds (or sometimes combined) word as:

document.csv

```
index  text
 0    my first java code was helloworld     
 1    my cardoor is totally broken
 2    I will buy a screwdriver to fix my bike
```

As seen above some words are combined or compound and I am using compound word splitter from [here](https://github.com/TimKam/compound-word-splitter) to fix this issue, however, I have trouble to apply it in each row of my document (like pandas series) and convert the document into a clean form of:

cleanDocument.csv

```
index  text
 0    my first java code was hello world     
 1    my car door is totally broken
 2    I will buy a screw driver to fix my bike
```

(I am aware of word such as screwdriver should be together, but my goal is cleaning the document). If you have a better idea for splitting only combined words, please let me know.

splitter code may works as:

```
import pandas as pd
import splitter ## This use enchant dict (pip install enchant requires)
data = pd.read_csv('document.csv.csv')
```

then, it should use:

```
splitter.split(data) ## ???
```

I already looked into something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59119824/how-to-split-a-compound-word-split-by-hyphen-into-two-individual-words) but this not work in my case. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use apply wit axis =1  :  Can you try the following

```
 data.apply(lambda x: splitter.split(j) for j in (x.split()), axis = 1)
```

I do not have splitter installed on my system. By looking at the link you have provided, I have this following code. Can you try:

```
def handle_list(m):
    ret_lst = []
    L = m['text'].split()
    for wrd in L:
        g = splitter.split(wrd)
        if g :
            ret_lst.extend(g)
        else:
            ret_lst.append(wrd)

    return ret_lst


dft.apply(handle_list, axis = 1)
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. I applied and I am getting an error as ```SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized```